# download multiple files to make up for not being able to download folders

Tags: python, download

I am trying to download the contents of folder which are all files to the my hard drive and this is the code I have been using. I have tried different variations of it but all of them print only the last item in the list for all

```
for i in seed:
    new_download=open(i,'w')
    print (i)
    new_download.close()
    open_file=open(i,'wb')
    for k in seed_id:
        client.file(k).download_to(open_file)
        print (k)
    open_file.close()
```

The files I want the name of the file in box to be matched in my machine.

Comment: Please edit your post to make it more readable, it is hard to understand the code otherwise, thanks. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I have edited your post for you, please check if the indentation is correct, because it was not possible to guess with 100% certainty how the code blocks should be indented.

Comment: Well...  what is seed, what is seed_id, what is client...

Comment: I am sorry seed is a list of all file names and seed ids is a list of all file ids i am using the box api and python sdk